# How to fix jupyter lab installation error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab

I'm usint gcp ubu

[image]

ntu 18.04 server and i wanted to install jupyterlab, but it doesn't work

Comment: Update the version of Python to 3.7 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot you have provided it looks like you are using the `Python 3.6` version. In accordance with @JohnHanely, I agree that you need to upgrade your Python version to `3.7`. According to this [PEP 563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/), this functionality `from __future__ import annotations` is available starting `Python3.7`

To install, use this command:

```
sudo apt install python3.7
```

To verify the installation:

```
python3 --version
```

You can also use a [virtual env](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) using the python version you require and running your code. This will help you to create isolated Python environments.

Comment: I installed python 3.7 but it still doesn't working, It shows me the same errow